# SSIS Transferring Data to an Oracle DB is Extremely Slow

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

We are transferring data to an Oracle Database from two different sources and it's extremely slow.

Please see notes and images below. Any suggestions?

Notes:

1. We're using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle.
2. One data source is SQL Server and includes about 5M records.
3. The second data source is Oracle and includes about 700M records.
4. When trying to transfer the SQL Server data, we broke it up into
   five "Data Flow Tasks" in the "Control Flow". Each "Data Flow Task"
   in turn use an "OLE DB Source" which internally uses a "SQL command"
   that effectively selects 1M of the 5M records. When we run this
   package it ran the first data flow task for about 3 hours and only
   transferred about 50,000 records until we ended the process.
5. We had similar experience with the Oracle data as well.
6. For some reason saving to a Oracle Destination is extremely slow.
7. Interestingly, we once transfer the same 700M records from Oracle to
   SQL Server (so the opposite direction) and it worked as expected in
   about 4.5 to 5 hours.

Images:

[image: Control Flow]

[image: Data Flow]

[image: OLE DB Source]

[image: Data Conversion]

[image: OLE DB Destination]

Comment: Consider using the Oracle OLE DB provider instead of Microsoft. Also consider creating a linked server.  It looks like you could just use a single SQL stored procedure with a linked server instead of SSIS for this task.  https://serverfault.com/questions/175257/how-to-install-oracle-ole-drivers-for-use-in-sql-server-2008-r2-x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. For those who may run into a similar problem in the future, I'm posting what finally worked for me.  **The answer was ... switching the provider. The ODBC or Attunity providers were much faster, by a factor of almost 800X.**

Remember that my goal was to move data *from a SQL Server Database to an Oracle database*. I originally used an OLE DB provider for both the source and destination. This provider works fine if you are moving data *from SQL Server to SQL Server* because it allows you to use the "Fast Load" option on the destination which in turn allows you to use batch processing.

However, the OLE DB provider doesn't allow the "Fast Load" option with an Oracle DB as the destination (couldn't get it to work and read elsewhere that it doesn't work). Because I couldn't use the "Fast Load" option I couldn't batch and instead was inserting records row by row which was extremely slow.

A colleague suggested trying ODBC and others suggested trying Microsoft's Attunity Connectors for Oracle. I didn't think the difference would be so great because in my experience ODBC had similar (and sometimes less) performance than OLE DB (hadn't tried Attunity). BUT... that was when *moving data from and to a SQL Server database* or staying in the Microsoft world.

When moving data from a SQL Server database to an Oracle database, there was a huge difference! Both ODBC and Attunity out performed OLE DB dramatically.

Here were my summarized performance test results inserting 5.4M records from a SQL Server database to an Oracle Database.

When doing all the work on one local computer.

- OLE DB source and destination inserted **12 thousand records per minute** which would have taken **approx. 7 hours** to complete.
- ODBC source and destination inserted 9 Million records per minute which only took **approx. 30 seconds** to complete.

When moving data from one network/remote computer to another network/remote computer.

- OLE DB source and destination inserted **115 records per minute** which would have taken **approx. 32 days** to complete.
- ODBC source and destination inserted **1 Million records per minute** which only took **approx. 5 minutes** to complete.

Big difference!

Now why when working locally it only took 30 seconds and remotely it took 5 minutes is another issue for another day, but for now I have something workable (it should be slower on the network, but surprised it's that much slower).

Thanks again to everyone!

Extra notes:

- My OLE DB results were similar with either Microsoft's or Oracle OLE DB providers for Oracle databases.
- Attunity was a little faster than ODBC. I didn't get to test on remote servers or on larger data set, but locally it was a consitently about 2 to 3 seconds faster than ODBC. Those seconds could add up on a large data set so take note.

Answer (score 2):

On the Oracle side you can examine v$session to see where the time is being spent (if AWR is licensed on the Oracle instance you can use DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY or v$active_session_history).

I work on Oracle performance problems every day (over 300 production Oracle instances), so I feel qualified to say that I can't give you a specific answer to your question, but I can point you in the right direction.

Typical process mistakes that make inserts slow:

1. not using array insert
2. connecting to the DB for each insert (sound strange? believe me
   I've seen DataStage and other ETL tools set-up this way)
3. app server/client not on same local area network as the Oracle instance
4. indexes on table(s) being inserted into (especially problematic with
   bit mapped indexes); requires index update and table update per
   statement
5. redo log files too small on Oracle instance (driving up
   redo log file switching)
6. log_buffer parameter on DB side too small
7. not enough db writers (see db_writer_processes initialization
   parameter)
8. committing too often

Comment: Thanks for the response I'll take a look and see what I find.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a bunch of observations and questions...

Any one of the components in the data pipeline could be the bottleneck.

You first need to observe the row counts when running interactively in SSIS and see if there is any obvious clogging going on - i.e. do you have a large rowcount right before your Data conversion transformation and a low one after? Or is it at the Oracle destination? Or is it just taking a long time to come out of SQL? A quick way to check the SQL side is to dump it to a local file instead - that mostly measures the SQL select performance without any blocking from Oracle.

When you run your source query in SQL Server, how long does it take to return all rows?

Your data conversion transformation can be performed in the source query. Every transformation requires set up of buffers, memory etc. and can slow down and block your dataflow. Avoid these and do it in the source query instead

Various buffers and config that exists in Oracle driver. Already addressed in detail by @RogerCornejo. For read performance out of Oracle, I have found altering FetchBufferSize made a huge difference, but you are doing writes here so that's not the case.

Lastly, where are the two database servers and the SSIS client tool situated network wise? If you are running this across three different servers then you have network throughput to consider.

If you use a linked server as suggested, note that SSIS doesn't do any processing at all so you take that whole piece out of the equation

And if you're just looking for the fastest way to transfer data, you might find that dumping to a file and bulk inserting is the fastest

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm reviewing options now

Comment: Good advice @nic.mcdermaid!

Comment: It starts with a small row count before the conversion and a similar small count after. We ran it overnight and after approx 8 hrs it's still running and has about 1.2M before the conversion and 300k after. It takes only 2-3 minutes to return the whole query in SQL. We needed the data conversion because we ran into a Unicode string error when converting from SQL to Oracle.

Comment: It seems that's at least one of your issues. What exact error did you get? I suggest you change your dataflow to do the conversion in the source SQL. Please post the error, and the data type of the SQL column and the Oracle column

Comment: Thanks for responding. The error was "cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string". I figured out that when using the OLE DB provider between SQL Server and Oracle, it's a little more sensitive about the data types selected on source vs destination.